# crystal report : set image for background of report (watermark)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to set image as report background. I insert new section before details-section and insert picture there. and in the Section Expert set "Underlay Following Section" to true. that's worked but my tables remain blew. I also create new report and set it's background and insert the main report as a sub-report inside it. this way good and the picture remains blew but page headers and other setting dose not work properly.
Can someone help me?

Comment: I use the Fast Report for this. it is better than CR

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a new `Page Header` section, putting that section to the top (this section should be `Page Header *A*`), and setting that section to `Underlay Following Sections`. This way, the watermark image will appear in every page, and will be the first thing in every page.